# Ubuntu 9.1 - Audio coming from both speakers and headphones

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, audio, speakers, headphones

I have an HP Compaq nc8230 that has an annoying little problem with it's audio devices in Ubuntu 9.1. When I have the headphones plugged in, the audio continues to play simultaneously  through the speakers no matter what. I'm not sure what kind of sound card this computer has, but in WIndows XP, Vista, 7 and OSx86 I didn't have this problem. I've tried using 3 different headphones and it didn't change anything. Please help.

Comment: I've seen the same thing with my card (built in Realtek HDA). I just assumed it was a driver issue; didn't really investigate much. - My solution was just to turn the speakers off xD - Sorry I can't offer any real help.

Comment: I have no option to turn my speakers  off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [DebuggingSoundProblems/KarmicCaveats](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems/KarmicCaveats) . you can see different ways of diagnosing sound problems at Karmic.

I also found out that kind of similar problems at Ubuntu Forum. Sound coming from [both internal speakers & headphones?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1426151). and Sound in both speakers and headphones on [HP Pavilion](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8858001). 
hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I followed the forum link and then after using the alsamixer command and turning one of them all the way done, it stopped. I'm back to Windows though, because I couldn't get Visual Studio to work with Wine.

Comment: running VS with wine might not be okay :)